# Angular cli 9.0.4 creating service module error

Tags: angular-cli

I am making angular project and need to add service for get posts.

My version is **Angular cli 9.0.4**

i am typing `ng g s services/posts--module=app.module` but i got below error;

`'Unknown option: '--module'`

```
Unknown option: 'app'
```

Can you explain why its happening and what how to fix this issue? All helps will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Could you confirm that the lack of a space between `services/posts` and `--module=app.module` is a typo and not what you're actually running.

Comment: output became Unknown option: '--module'